# how to deduplicate values that have not changed since the first time value was established

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

When using the pandas df.duplicated function it will flag anything that duplicates.  I am trying to only flag up duplicates that have not changed since the last time they changed.  To demonstrate the desired outcome I have a status column that shows keep or remove.  Ideally the duplicated function would drop anything tagged as remove.

The goal is to allow duplicate values but only if a different value existed since the last time it changed.

For example, I have a list of store discount values for each month.  They have a 10% discount in May and December and 5% all other months.  I want to track the unique discounts over time without storing a record for each month.

here is a link to the csv data if you want to try it out [gist](https://gist.github.com/bfmcneill/2a5eed489df3b0e2149ed56f177887be)

here is an image of the csv data after running this code
[csv data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAXlv.png)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create workbook(csv) path
wb_path = './eav_dedup_test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(wb_path)

# chop off the notes column (the last column)
df = df.iloc[:,0:-1]


# list unique entities
entities = df['entity_id'].unique()
list(entities)

# list unique entity attributes
attributes = df['attribute'].unique()
list(attributes)

# Sort by entity, attribute, effective date - all with ascending values
df.sort_values(
    ['entity_id', 'attribute', 'date_effective'],
    ascending=[True,True,True]
    ,inplace=True
)

# create an is_dup column and compare it with what to keep and what to remove
df['is_dup']=df.duplicated(subset=['entity_id','attribute','value'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
df['is_dup'] = df.groupby(['entity_id','attribute'])['value'].diff() == 0
```

check if it works:

```
pd.crosstab(df['is_dup'],df['status'])

# status  keep  remove
# is_dup              
# False     24       0
# True       0      12
```